# i'm trying to increase the invoice number automatically

Tags: php, mysql, invoice

Hello every one i'm trying to increase the invoice number automatically and the problem is when it comes to 2019-10 automatically return to 2019-01 she not complete increasing can some one help me

```
<?php  

    $value2='';
    //Query to fetch last inserted invoice number
    $query = "SELECT numfacturation from facturation order by numfacturation DESC LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $con->query($query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($stmt) > 0) {
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
            $value2 = $row['numfacturation'];
            $value2 = substr($value2, 6, 13);//separating numeric part
            $value2 = $value2 + 1;//Incrementing numeric part
            $value2 = "2019-" . sprintf('%02s', $value2);//concatenating incremented value
            $value = $value2; 
        }
    } 
    else {
        $value2 = "2019-01";
        $value = $value2;
    }

?>
```

Comment: What's not working? And what happens when you get 100 invoices?

Comment: i wonder what the structure and data of the `facturation` table are.  hey, do you have a `primary key` with `auto_increment` for your invoice numbers?  you can always add the date to the front of it when you display it to customers.

Comment: Is the number after the - a sequential number within year?

Comment: yes it s the year i will make it as current year after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the manual for [substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php);

> ```
> substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] ) : string
> ```
>
> Returns the portion of string specified by the start and length
>   parameters.
>
> **string**
>
> The input string. Must be one character or longer.
>
> **start**
>
> If **start** is non-negative, the returned string will **start** at
>   the **start**'th position in **string**, counting from zero. For
>   instance, in the string '*abcdef*', the character at position *0* is
>   '*a*', the character at position *2* is '*c*', and so forth.

Note the part "**counting from zero**".

Consider the two examples:

```
$value2 = '2019-XY';
$value2 = substr($value2, 6, 13);
var_dump($value2);
```

Result: `string(1) "Y"`

```
$value2 = '2019-XY';
$value2 = substr($value2, 5, 13);
var_dump($value2);
```

Result: `string(2) "XY"`

So you need to count the characters starting with position `0`.

```
string:   2019-10
position: 0123456
```

As you see, your number starts at position `5` (not `6`).

Also note that you use `13` as length. But if your numbers are always two digits long, you should use:

```
$value2 = substr($value2, 5, 2);
```

Comment: thank you so much so clear it works now i wanna make 2019 as the current year how can i do it any way i will search thank you again for your help

Comment: @BoularhrassNisrine If `date('Y')` doesn't answer your comment, consider to post a new question.